# lambda function predicate to use for find_if which compares compound type map element

Tags: c++, if-statement, find, predicate

Please see the following code snippet below:

```
typedef boost::tuple<std::string, int, std::string> TUPLE;
std::map<int, TUPLE> m;

std::find_if
    (
        m.begin(),
        m.end(),
        boost::lambda::bind
            (
                &std::map<int, TUPLE>::value_type::second_type::head,
                boost::lambda::bind
                (
                    &std::map<int, TUPLE>::value_type::second,
                    boost::lambda::_1
                )
            )
        ==
        "someString"
    );
```

I am trying to create a predicate for find_if (using boost lambda) and compare the first element of a tuple to a string. However, is there any way to make this work like something like:

```
typedef boost::tuple<std::string, int, std::string> TUPLE;
std::map<int, TUPLE> m;

std::find_if
    (
        m.begin(),
        m.end(),
        boost::lambda::bind
            (
                &std::map<int, TUPLE>::value_type::second_type::get<0>,
                boost::lambda::bind
                (
                    &std::map<int, TUPLE>::value_type::second,
                    boost::lambda::_1
                )
            )
        ==
        "someString"
    );
```

I changed second_type::head to second_type::get<0> but it does not compile.
I am trying to create predicate which compares the 1st or 2nd element of the tuple to some string.

This is one of the errors i am getting:

Error   29  error C2780: 'const boost::lambda::lambda_functor>,detail::bind_tuple_mapper::type>> boost::lambda::bind(const Arg1 &)' : expects 1 arguments - 2 provided

Is there any way to specifically compare the nth element of the tuple? (not just the head)
I tried representing the tuple elements as struct and it works but I will be grateful if there is a way to use tuple.

Side note: I cannot use `[](){}` notation because of compiler version.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I don't know about boost but with C++11 lambdas that would be the following:

```
typedef std::tuple<std::string, int, std::string> TUPLE;
std::map<int, TUPLE> m;

std::find_if(m.begin(), m.end(), [] (const std::pair<int, TUPLE>& v) {
    return v.second.get<1>() == "someString";
});
```

Guessing from the boost documentation, this would be:

```
std::find_if(m.begin(), m.end(), 
    return boost::lambda::_1.second.second == "someString");
```